# How to bring up Eclipse on xterm in Solaris

Tags: eclipse, xterm

Is there a way to bring up Eclipse on xterm in Sun Solaris. I tried to execute the ./eclipse  command, but it does not bring up eclipse.

**Update:**

The DISPLAY is set. Please find the details below.

% echo $DISPLAY
169.52.56.88:0.0
% echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/jdk/jdk1.5.0_14/
% which java
/usr/jdk/jdk1.5.0_14/bin/java
% cd ~schoudha
:/home/schoudha> cd eclipse
:/home/schoudha/eclipse> ./eclipse &
[1] 23699
:/home/schoudha/eclipse> bg %1
[1]  + ./eclipse &
[1]  + Exit 15              ./eclipse

> ps -ef | grep spantul1
>   spantul1 19475 19295   0 00:57:38 pts/101     0:00 -csh
>   spantul1 19295 15910   0 00:57:29 ?           0:00 /usr/openwin/bin/xterm -ls -sl 200 -display 169.52.56.88:0.0
>   spantul1 24041 19475   0 00:59:59 pts/101     0:01 ps -ef
>   spantul1 24042 19475   0 00:59:59 pts/101     0:00 grep spantul1

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: eclipse requires an X display and cannot display inside an xterm.  Obviously you have an X display if you're running an xterm, but does the environment have DISPLAY set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are in the eclipse folder, `./eclipse` should run it, however, you will probably want to detach it from the terminal instance, so:

```
./eclipse &
bg %1 # assuming it's the only job running.
disown eclipse
```

Should give you a running instance and free up the terminal session.

If you are not in the eclipse folder, best thing to do is add it to the `$PATH` and then you can run if from anywhere.